# can't find the stacknaigator

Tags: react-native

```
 import React, {Component} from "react";
 import {View,Text,StyleSheet}from "react-native";
 import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
export default createSwitchNavigator({
 AuthLoading : AuthLoadingScreen
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

1. by doing this simply it shows the can't find the authscreen
2. exporting it in default why this error happen

Comment: and while importing the authscreen it show development error

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

`import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';`

with this line of code

`import { createSwitchNavigator , StackActions } from 'react-navigation'`

And import all your file which you want to use inside this navigator

Comment: the component for route 'AuthLoading' must be a react component now this error popup

Comment: check that you have imported react  component inside that file or not,,,,,

Comment: Note: any .js file is not a component of react native we have to make it the component by importing the component from react here is the line 

import React, { Component } from 'react';


understood ?

Comment: May be the problem in the code of switch navigator so refer some example of it and try again